# Second conditional statement is not triggering -

Tags: jquery, if-statement, checkbox

By default all of the checkboxes are checked, and has a parent child relation. When all the checkboxes are unchecked I want to add a class.But 
The second else if statement is not working -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#treeList :checkbox').change(function() {
        $(this).siblings('ul').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).parentsUntil('#treeList', 'ul').siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        }
        else {
            $(this).parentsUntil('#treeList', 'ul').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var childSelected = $this.find(':checkbox:checked').length;
                if (!childSelected) {
                    $this.prev(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // the second else if statement is not working
    if ($('#treelist :checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0) {
        $('.row.cd-feed-wrapper').addClass('visible');
    }
    else if ($('#treelist :checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
        $('.row.cd-feed-wrapper').addClass('hidden');
    }

});
```

The first one when the page loads.

codepen setup : http://codepen.io/Assert/pen/BLBjpk?editors=1010

```
<ul id="treeList">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole" checked> mCRC
  <ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole" checked> STIVARGA Efficacy
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole" checked> Long-Term Responders
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole" checked> STIVARGA in Clinical Practice
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole" checked> STIVARGA AE Management
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole" checked> Dosing
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole" checked> Patient Communication
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole" checked> Case Studies
  </li>
</ul>

<li>
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole" checked> GIST
</li>
```

Comment: You only run that `if` statement when the page loads. Presumably you need to add it in to your `change()` event handler too...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan could you tell me a little more

Comment: I did not complain , why would you think I am bothered, sir @T.J.Crowder

Comment: I am sorry, I will keep that in mind,sir @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Id is wrong.

You are using #treelist in your jquery code and instead of #treeList.

Javascript doesn't work that way

So In all the cases it is getting 0 only and goes into first IF condition.

Comment: That's a good spot, but fixing it doesn't fix the problem; there's at least one other problem, I'm fairly sure two.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nim118

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  yes sir, I used both of your solutions to get the result I want.

        $('#treeList :checkbox').change(function() {
            if ($('#treeList :checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0) {
               alert("checked");
           } else if ($('#treeList :checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
              alert("not-checked");
             }
          });

Answer (score 1):

[Rory's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243353/second-conditional-statement-is-not-triggering?noredirect=1#comment65823140_39243353) is an answer:

> You only run that `if` statement when the page loads. Presumably you need to add it in to your `change()` event handler too.

So put the code in a function. Call that function in `ready`, **and** call it in your `change` handler.